# Jsoup - Printing element.data() prints nothing

Tags: java, eclipse, css-selectors, html-parsing, jsoup

So I'm trying to print the text inside a certain `<div>` element in a `HTML` document.

For some reason, when I call the `data()` method i get an empty console.

```
public class Program 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Program starts:");
        try 
        {

            Document document2 = Jsoup.connect("http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/eminem/mynameis.html").get();
            Element element3 = document2.select("div.lyricsh").first();

            System.out.println(element3.data());
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } // End of main method
} // End of Program class
```

I put the selector in this `HTML` document http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/eminem/mynameis.html. It's on line 150.

What's wrong with my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `System.out.println(element3.text());`

The `data()` method is for [dataNodes](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/DataNode.html), e.g. if you want to get the inside of a `<script>` tag.

`text()` will get the (combined) text of all [textNodes](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/TextNode.html) within the element. If you want only the text that is attached to the very element in question you can use `ownText()`

Comment: Bingo. Cheers mate. I will accept the answer when i could.

Comment: You can't accept the answer? Can you explain your difficulties with it?

Comment: I need to wait 15 minutes from the post time ;).

Comment: Ah... I see.Well then do it later :)

Comment: BTW. I'm having trouble with something else in `Jsoup`. May i have your email or something? I need just 1 more question please.

Comment: Ask it as new Jsoup tagged question. If I know the answer I will respond.